# data declaration - use 3 parameter

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

i'm going to use the data types now but there is sth what i just know from other programming languages.
imagine that "Date" get's (Year Month Day)

when i have

```
data Month = Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec
data Date = Date Int Month Int
```

and i want to have a funktion

```
showDate :: Date -> String
```

how can i take the 3. parameter from the datatype Date to create the year?
or to describe better.. how can i create a String with returns for example "May 18 2017"

in other languages i would write date[2] for the 3. parameter or date[0] for the 1.

Thanks for help!

Comment: `showDate (Date day month year) = <do something with day, month, and year>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do `pattern matching` in Haskell:

```
data Month = Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec deriving (Show)
data Date = Date Int Month Int

showData :: Date -> String
showDate (Date day mon year) = "Date is: " ++ (show day) ++ " " ++ (show mon) ++  " " ++ (show year)
```

Note that I derive `Show` instance for `Month` type above by using `deriving (Show)`. Instead of doing it automatically, you can give your hand crafted `Show` instances like this:

```
instance Show Month where
    show Jan = "January"
    show Feb   = "February"
    .... and so on
```

Demo:

```
*Main> showDate (Date 3 Feb 2017)
"Date is: 3 Feb 2017"
```

Or even like this:

```
data Month = Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec deriving (Show)
data Date = Date Int Month Int deriving (Show)
```

This will automatically derive the Show instance of your data type.

```
*Main> show (Date 3 Feb 2017)
"Date 3 Feb 2017"
```

Comment: I know the patternmaching but i really tried all i know in syntax!
thanks for helping me!

Comment: You should use pattern matching. Pattern Matching is not an afterthought added to the language, but it is part of it's very core.

Comment: @R.Mayer and in case you are wondering, *there is no other way*, given the way you have declared things.  If you had defined date with record fields, e.g. `data Date = Date { day :: Int, month :: Month, year :: Int }`, then you could use e.g `year date` to extract the year.  But without such a definition, pattern matching is the only way.